# Sql statement using Insert and Case

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i need sql statement that allow me to do this :

```
update table set colomn1=val1 and colomn2=val2  when colomn1=value
else set colomn1=val11 and colomn2=val22  when colomn1=otherValue
```

please help

Comment: You can use the `CASE` to get what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `CASE...WHEN` into the Update statement

```
UPDATE table 
SET colomn1 = CASE WHEN colomn1 = value THEN value 
                   WHEN colomn1 = otherValue THEN val11 
                   ELSE somedefaultvalue END,
    colomn2 = CASE WHEN colomn1 = value THEN value2 
                   WHEN colomn1 = otherValue THEN val22  
                   ELSE somedefaultvalue END
```